# Django session cookies with and without www

Tags: django, apache

I have a website built with Django and running Apache2 that can be accessed both at `domain.com` and `www.domain.com`, but if you log in on one, the cookie is only set for that specific version of the domain.

How can I set it so that either the cookie works on both versions of the domain, or that `www.domain.com` redirects to `domain.com`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set [`SESSSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#session-cookie-domain) to the common denominator, which is valid for both of them.

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.domain.com'
```